# Replacing HTML entities in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following html, which is a dl tag containing a dt tag with a class of toggle and containing the FAQ, and then a dd tag with a class of expand that contains the answer to the FAQ:

```
<dl>
<dt class="toggle">&#9660; Here is a FAQ</dt>
<dd class="expand">
    <p>And here is the answer</p>
</dd>
....
</dl>
```

and the following jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('.expand').hide();

    $('.toggle').click(function() {
        var $expand = $(this).next('.expand');
        if ($expand.is(':hidden')) {
            $expand.slideDown();
        } else {
            $expand.slideUp();
        }
    });
});
```

This function expands or collapses the FAQ answer.

What I would really like to do is additionally replace the ▼ down arrow with a ▲ up arrow when the text is expanded. I do not want to use images or sprites.

No matter how I try to encode / use the slice or substring functions I have so far been unable to achieve this.

Any comments appreciated, but be kind as this is my first post.

Comment: Your first question is well formulated, which is rare enough. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Place the entities inside of a span. Have both elements there to begin with and set a class on the dt on state and css can show/hide them.

Comment: Many thanks for that, and to all those who have taken the trouble to provide the elegant solutions that I now have at my disposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is just to rely on CSS to show hide the up and down arrows.

```js
$(".toggle").on("click", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
});
```

```css
.toggle {
    cursor: pointer;  
}

.toggle > span + span {
  display : none;
}

.toggle.open > span {
  display : none;
}

.toggle.open > span + span {
  display : inline;
}

.toggle + dd.expand { display : none; } 
.toggle.open + dd.expand { display : block;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl>
<dt class="toggle"><span>&#9650</span><span>&#9660;</span> Here is a FAQ</dt>
<dd class="expand">
    <p>And here is the answer</p>
</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: All these solutions work just fine, but the css solution is the cleanest. The problem with the italic tag solution is that - would you believe - some fonts italicise the up/down arrows and make them look awful!

Comment: So you change the <i> to a span in that solution... ;)

Comment: Exactly! And of course you have 2 span tags, one for the up arrow and one for the down, and just toggle hide and show.

Answer (score 1):

Place your arrow inside an `<i>` tag so that you can target it using jQuery:

```
<dt class="toggle"><i>&#9660;</i> Here is a FAQ 1</dt>
```

**Example**:

```js
$(function () {

  $('.expand').hide();

  $('.toggle').click(function() {
    var $expand = $(this).next('.expand');
    var isHidden = $expand.is(':hidden');
    $expand.slideToggle();
    $("i", this).html(isHidden? "&#9650;" : "&#9660;");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl>
  <dt class="toggle"><i>&#9660;</i> Here is a FAQ 1</dt>
  <dd class="expand">
    <p>1 And here is the answer</p>
  </dd>
  <dt class="toggle"><i>&#9660;</i> Here is a FAQ 2</dt>
  <dd class="expand">
    <p>2 And here is the answer</p>
  </dd>
  <dt class="toggle"><i>&#9660;</i> Here is a FAQ 3</dt>
  <dd class="expand">
    <p>3 And here is the answer</p>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Worked immediately and a nice clean solution. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace by the Unicode value of the character instead of the HTML entity.

Character ▼ is `9660` in decimal, and `25BC` in hexadecimal. Its HTML entity is therefore `&#9660;`, and its JavaScript string form is `"\u25BC"`.

Same goes for ▲, which is `9650` in decimal and `25B2` in hexadecimal.

So you can replace back and forth in text strings with:

```
.replace("\u25BC", "\u25B2");
```

Working example:

```js
$(function () {
    $('.expand').hide();

    $('.toggle').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $expand = $this.next('.expand');
        if ($expand.is(':hidden')) {
            $expand.slideDown();
            $this.text($this.text().replace("\u25BC", "\u25B2"));
        } else {
            $expand.slideUp();
            $this.text($this.text().replace("\u25B2", "\u25BC"));
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl>
<dt class="toggle">&#9660; Here is a FAQ</dt>
<dd class="expand">
    <p>And here is the answer</p>
</dd>
....
</dl>
```